# Java-Collections, cannot overwrite old value with new value

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I got a question regarding Java-Collections. I iterate through a Java-Collection and if an if-clause is true, I want to change the entry of the Collection. Within the if-clause body the new Value is accepted, but if I want to print the whole collection later, it prints out again the Collection with the old value.

Here the Code:

```
public boolean checkConsumeStorageCapacity(Multimap<String, Values> mm1,   Multimap<String, Values> mm2)
{
    boolean enoughStorageCapacity = false;

     Multimap<String, Values> mmApp = mm1;

     Multimap<String, Values> mmHW = mm2;

     Collection<Values> colA = mmApp.get("Storage");
     Collection<Values> colH = mmHW.get("Memory");
for (Values vA2 : colA) {
    for (Values vH2 : colH) {

        if (vA2.getName().equals("Size") && vH2.getName().equals("Size")) {

            float StoSize = Float.parseFloat(vA2.getValue());
            float MemSize = Float.parseFloat(vH2.getValue());
            float maintainableStoSize = StoSize * maintainabilityfactor;

            if (MemSize >= maintainableStoSize) {

                MemSize -= maintainableStoSize;
                vH2.setValue(String.valueOf(MemSize));

                String s = vH2.getValue();
                System.out.println(s);

                enoughStorageCapacity = true;
                return enoughStorageCapacity;

            }
            break;
        }

    }
}

System.out.println(colH);
```

Values is a object containing 3 String. The getters/setters are all declared correctly. Printing out s gives the correct value, but printing out colH gives again the old value. Isnt setting the new Value enough, do I additionally have to commit anything in the Collection?

Thanks a lot in advance.

edit:
here the values class, for further understanding.

```
public class Values {

private String name;
 private String type;
 private String value;

public Values(String name, String type, String value)
 {
    this.name = name; 
    this.type = type; 
    this.value = value;
}
public String getName()
 {
    return name;
 }
public String getType()
 {
    return type;
 }
public String getValue()
 {
    return value;
 }
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name; 
}
public void setValue(String value)
{
    this.value = value; 
}
public void setType(String type)
{
    this.type = type; 
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "name=" + name + ", type=" + type + ", value=" + value;
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of collection is colH? An ArrayList?

Comment: I didnt specified the collection kind. I tried ArrayList before, but thats not conform get-Method of the Multimap mmApp.

Comment: I am confused: You only set the new value for vH2 if MemSize >= maintainableStoSize, in which case the function returns and never reaches System.out.println(colH), right?

Comment: Yes you are right. The System.out.print is just for clarification. If the if-clause is true, then I change the Value and the functions returns.

Comment: Strange. Looks like it should work to me. Does Values implement toString and return the right value?

Comment: the inside system.out prints the correct value, the outside one the whole collection, with the old value. Thats my problem, that the value in the Collection is not changed after the setValue-Method.

Comment: How do you create your `MultiMap`s? I’m pretty sure you use org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap and I need to know what is the Factory given at creation time.

Comment: Could you provide the toString() method of the Values class? Or even the full Values class actually ;)

Comment: The inside System.out.println prints the String that is returned by vH2.getValue(). The outside prints the collection by using Values#toString - that's why I thought the problem might be the implementation of toString().

Comment: @EtienneMiret I use com.google.common.collect.Multimap and edited my code and inserted the codepiece, where the multimaps are created. Aprreciate if you have a look at it.

Comment: @Alika87 seems you forgot to include the codepiece where multimaps are created. We need to know which implementation of com.google.common.collect.Multimap is being used.

Comment: @EtienneMiret Do you mean this? com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap.create()

The multimaps are created in a different class and passed over to the current class.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed to know. But know, I have no idea as why your code doesn’t work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way of dealing with such pointer issues is to initialize a second collection before the loop. As you iterate through add the values that you want to stay the same to the collection and then in the if statement add the changed value/object. This costs a little more memory but no real performance loss

Something like this:

```
list<T> originallist;
list<T> tmp = new list
for(x : originalList)
{
if(condition)
{
//do things
tmp.add(changedValue)
}
else
{
 tmp.add(x)
 }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: If anyone is going to use this technique, I would recommend pre-sizing the new list.

Comment: It's pseudocode to be honest not meant to be copied and pasted. I don't know that it makes all that much of a difference if you use a regular list. I have been in c# recently but I think its fairly similar in java.

Comment: @pamphlet I actually use this technique in my code fairly often. What is the benefit in pre-sizing a list? I thought adding to a list was O(1) regardless

Comment: I'm thinking of `ArrayList` specifically. As the list grows, the backing array will need to be reallocating and copied from time to time. Overall this is considered to be amortized O(1), but it's significantly more expensive than not doing all that extra work. Your use case is one where you know an upper bound on the size of it at construction time, so you can definitely get a performance gain by avoiding frequent allocates, copies (and freeing on the GColl side). `new ArrayList(oldList.size())`

Comment: Does it matter if it is just just List<T>() in c#? I don't really use ArrayLists

Comment: Can I use something else than a list? Because ArrayList dont accept mmApp.get("Safety") as an input, though ArrayList is also an Collection. mmApp.get("Safety") gets the value in the multimap with key "safety" and the return values are a collections of values.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html LinkedList or stack